# Cycles: AMD and Nvidia GPUs in the same machine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

Now that we're getting proper Cycles on AMD/ATI cards (in 2.75, and in testbuilds now), will we be able to mix them with Nvidia cards using CUDA? Would it be possible to GPU render with CUDA and OpenCL at the same time? If not, could you run 2 instances of blender, each using a different card and run 2 separate renders?

Comment: The separate applications should work, not sure about the side-by-side implementation though.

Comment: I believe on OSX opencl support works with both amd and nvidia cards so opencl would use both. Other platforms may need 2 instances.