# Cross brand GPU's?

Tags: gpu

Has anyone tried using to different GPU's (i.e. an Nvidia paired with an AMD?) I know blender has the great feature of using two or more installed nvidia GPU's without any fuss, as that is what I am doing now, but one of them is not doing so hot anymore. I want to see if I can replace it with a more cost effective AMD.

Comment: I asked this awhile ago but didn't get a straight answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27983/cycles-amd-and-nvidia-gpus-in-the-same-machine

You can certainly run 2 separate instances of Blender with each using a different card.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, supported feature set is quite different for AMD OpenCL and NVidia CUDA, render results could possibly differ between each device, which might result in an incoherent image with buckets from different devices not matching with one another. The way this question is phrased is offtopic for this site, its actually more of a discussion suited for a forum.